# Delete last N bytes in a large file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way to delete the last few bytes in a large file in node.js without buffering the entire file into the memory and saving it. Is there any way to do this?

Edit: By "last few bytes" I mean characters.
I have tried fs.truncate but it just deletes the entire file's contents.

Truncate not working example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.truncate('C:\\NODEAPP\\totruncate.txt', 0, function(){
    console.log('File got cleared... Is 0 supposed to delete the last character?');
})
```

Comment: Please set up an exact scenario. What does "the last few bytes" exactly mean?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the [`fs` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)?

Comment: You should provide your code to find out why fs.truncate isn't working as expected.

Comment: Of course if you truncate the file to 0 bytes, all content is deleted. :-))

Comment: btw.: "last few bytes" could mean: the last 10 bytes, all after a fixed length, all from the last new line, ... You should learn to exactly ask what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The 0 means how long the file should be afterwards.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.truncate('C:\\NODEAPP\\totruncate.txt', 5, function(){
    console.log('Kept first 5 bytes, deleted the rest.');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for my case. I wanted to delete the last character `,` (comma) from a JSON file I was assembling.

```js
const filePath = "./myHumongousFile.json";

//First we get the total bytes (size) of that file
const stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

//Then we truncate 
fs.truncateSync(filePath, stat.size - 1);
```